# Toggle switch won't automatically change position to the initial state

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using this code different text is displayed based on the toggle switch state. the toggle switch state is also being stored in the local browser storage, in order to remember what content was displayed before the page reloaded. when the page reloads a function needs to read which state of the toggle switch is stored in the local browser storage and display the content that was previously displayed. I'm guessing when the page reloads, the toggle switch state functions is being ignored because of the css design.

```js
// Function to switch between automatic and manual watering instructions
function HowToFunction(checked) {
var switchElement = document.getElementById("HowToCheck");
var text1 = document.getElementById("HowToAutomatic");
var text2 = document.getElementById("HowToManual");

  if (switchElement.checked) {
          text1.style.display = "block";
          text2.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          text1.style.display = "none";
          text2.style.display = "block";
        }

        // Store the checkbox state in the browser's local storage
        localStorage.setItem('HowToCheckboxState', switchElement.checked);
  }

// Function to read the checkbox state from local storage and update the display
function updateDisplayFromLocalStorage() {
  // Get the stored checkbox state from local storage
  const storedCheckboxState = localStorage.getItem('HowToCheckboxState');

  // Get references to HTML elements
  const switchElement = document.getElementById("HowToCheck");
  const text1 = document.getElementById("HowToAutomatic");
  const text2 = document.getElementById("HowToManual");

  // Update the checkbox state and display based on the stored state
  if (storedCheckboxState === 'true') {
    // If the stored state is 'true', display text1 and hide text2
    switchElement.checked = true;
    text1.style.display = "block";
    text2.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    // If the stored state is 'false' or null, hide text1 and display text2
    switchElement.checked = false;
    text1.style.display = "none";
    text2.style.display = "block";
  }
}

// Call the update function when the page loads
window.addEventListener('load', updateDisplayFromLocalStorage);
```

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 42px;
  height: 75px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5dc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "\1F322";
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f5f5dc;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #333333;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #adb57e;
}

/*input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #f5f5dc;
}*/

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-32px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-32px);
  transform: translateY(-32px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 42px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="toogle-switch">
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id="HowToCheck" onclick="HowToFunction(this.checked)">
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</div>
<br>


<!--Manual watering-->

<div id="HowToManual" style="display: none;">
<!-- Content -->
</div>


<!--Automatic watering-->
<div id="HowToAutomatic" style="display: none;">
<!-- Content -->
</div>
```

ChatGPT can't help haha

Comment: You can edit your question, to put your code inside a Stack snippet, that can be ran right on this website. You also don't need the first line on all of the blockcodes - it will actually give an error in JS.